# Finding all paths in graph, Python

Tags: python, graph

I have a graph, represented in a way of a dictionary with pairs `key|value - A node|Edges to other nodes`. Example:

```
{'5': '1 2 3 W', '0': '1 2 3 W', '2': '0 4 5 L', '1': '0 4 5 L', '4': '1 2 3 W', '3': '0 4 5 L'}
```

(`W` and `L` are the marks of the nodes)
What is the best approach to find all the paths `W-L-W-L` or `L-W-L-W`? (Python 3.+)

Comment: Are you looking for a graph library/package or is this more of a homework question (how to write an algorithm)?

Answer (score -1):

A "breadth first search" algorithm may be what you are looking for. You can find a good explanation and a Python implementation [here](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Graphs/ImplementingBreadthFirstSearch.html).